# Unit test freezes during the execution

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, webclient, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

So, here I am with my issue - I am trying to make unit tests for my app. I have 2 services, lets call them Foo and Bar and Foo is nothing but a proxy for the Bar.

So, the router of the Foo service looks like this:

```kotlin
fun fooRoute(...) = coRouter {
    . . .
    GET("/something", fooHandler::findSomething)
    . . .
}
```

The handler that makes requests to the Bar service looks like this:

```kotlin
fun fooHandler(barClient: WebClient) {
    . . .
    suspend fun findSomething(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val response = barClient.get()
            .uri(...)
            .accept(...)
            .awaitExchange()
        . . .
        return when (response.statusCode()) {
            HttpStatus.OK -> {
                ServerResponse
                    . . .
                    .bodyValueAndAwait(response.awaitBody<SomeType>())
            }
            else -> { 
                ServerResponse
                    . . .
                    .buildAndAwait()
            }
        }
    }
    . . .
}
```

And when I write test like this:

```kotlin
. . .
private val barClient = mockk<WebClient>()

private val fooHandler = FooHandler(barClient)
private val fooRouter = FooRouter()
private val fooClient = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(
    fooRouter.fooRoute(
        // mocks
        . . .
        fooHandler
    )
).build()

@Nested
inner class FindSomething {

    @Test
    fun `returns OK`() = runBlocking {

        val response = mockk<ClientResponse>()
        val spec = mockk<WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec<*>>()

        coEvery { response.awaitBody<SomeType>() } returns SomeType(...)
        coEvery { spec.awaitExchange() } returns response
        coEvery { barClient.get() } returns spec

        fooClient
            .get()
            .uri(...)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful

        . . .
    }
}
```

it just freezes forever... Well, I assume this happens because of some coroutine magic around it, but because I'm still newbie in this one, I can't understand what exactly is going on here. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welp, I solved the problem by writing my own exchange function based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301220/how-to-mock-spring-webflux-webclient) answer. Here an example of how I did this:

```kotlin
. . .
fun setUpBarClient(exchangeFunction: ExchangeFunction) {
    barClient = barClient.mutate()
        .exchangeFunction(exchangeFunction)
        .build()

    // recreate fooHandler & fooClient
}

@Nested
inner class FindSomething {

    @Test
    fun `returns OK`() {

        // this one from org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunction

        val exchangeFunction = ExchangeFunction {
            Mono.just(
                ClientResponse.create(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header(...)
                    .body(...)
                    .build()
            )
        }

        setUpBarClient(exchangeFunction)

        fooClient
            .get()
            .uri(...)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful

        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you have 2 or more sequential calls to a second client you can stuck with a problem I'm getting right now. The problem is that you can provide only one exchange function in a moment, and if you are waiting another parameters from the client to proceed further (e.g. if you want to get status = OK at first, and then status = NO_CONTENT on the next step) you'll have to deal with it somehow.