# NullPointerException while Mocking Mono.just using mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux

```
    ### Method Implementation ###
    
    WebClient apiClient ; // This is instantiated through constructor
    Request req = new Request();
    Mono<Response> monoResponse
    try{
    monoResponse = apiClient.method(HttpMethod.DELETE).header("Authorization",<somevalue>).contentType(MediaType.APPLIATION_JSON).body(Mono.just(req),Request.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class);
    
    ### Mock ###
    @Mock WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;
    @Mock WebClient.RequestHeaderSpec requestHeaderSpec;
    @Mock WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec;
    @Mock WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;
    
    when(webClient.method(HttpMethod.DELETE).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    when(requestBodySpec.header(any(),any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    when(requestBodySpec.contentType(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
    
    when(requestBodySpec.body(Mono.just(request),Request.class)).thenReturn(requestHeaderSpec);   //**This line is showing NullPointerException**
    
    when(requestHeaderSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
    when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(ArgumentMatchers.<Class<Response>>notNull())).thenReturn(Mono.just(response));
    
  Request and Response object is created, and the values are set for the mock. NullPpointerException is getting when my flow hits .retrieve() part of the code. Please, someone, help me.

### StackTrace ###

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Object.lambda$execute$1(Object.java:89)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at Object.execute(Object.java:77)
    at ObjectTest.execute(ObjectTest.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:43)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:82)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

ObjectTest > execute FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Object.lambda$execute$1(Object.java:89)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
        at Object.execute(Object.java:77)
        at Test.execute(Test.java:197)
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

StackTrace Included. I tried replacing body mock with this  when(requestBodySpec.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec); as well. But no use. I think the problem is in mocking Mono.just object. Not sure what could be the issue. If there are different ways to mock mono.just object seperately and pass, please let me know.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar StackTrace Icluded

Comment: The default behavior of a mocked method is to return null . It’s impossible to say based on the haphazard code you’ve posted but most likely one of the methods called internally is returning null causing the NPE. A better approach would be run a mock web server and use real `WebClient` to connect to it. See [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/).

Comment: I agree, dont mock a webclient

Comment: I'd agreed with the comments above and give one other solution. You can add an `ExchangeFunction` into the `WebClient` instance you are injecting into your class under test to return the response you desire. Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660487/3047038

Answer (score 1):

As I am new to Mockito, and consider the time I got to fix this, I couldn't explore commented options.

I could fix this by changing this line:

```
when(requestBodySpec.body(Mono.just(request),Request.class)).thenReturn(requestHeaderSpec);
```

to

```
when(requestBodySpec.body(any(),eq(Request.class))).thenReturn(requestHeaderSpec);
```

This solved my Issue. Posting as this could help someone.