# How to mock Spring WebClient and builder

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock Spring WebClient and am having issues with the WebClient.builder() mocking. The mocks I've defined so far in my test are not being used, I think because this builder does not return my mock WebClient. How can I get the builder to return my mock?

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                        .defaultCodecs()
                        .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024))
                .build())
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection().compress(true)))
                .build();
```

and the WebClient is used as so:

```
response = webClient
            .get()
            .uri(URLDecoder.decode(someEndpoint.replace("\"", ""), CLIENT_ENCODING))
            .header(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + accessToken)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve().bodyToMono(JsonNode.class).block();
```

I do not see any problems with the mocks as I followed these solutions: [How to mock Spring WebFlux WebClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301220/how-to-mock-spring-webflux-webclient) but the mocks are not being used. How can I mock the builder/return my mock from the builder?

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the static method `builder()` of `WebClient`. Indeed, if this method is not mocked, mockito can't edit the behaviour of this method. Therefore, your mocked webClient is not used. To perfom that, you need to include this dependency in your `pom.xml` if you use maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will provide `mockStatic()` method on `Mockito` and can be used like :

```
MockedStatic<WebClient> webClientStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(WebClient.class);
webClientStatic.when(WebClient::builder).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
```

`webClientBuilder` must be mocked because we need to change behaviour of its method `build()` to return your mocked webClient.

```
Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mockedWebClient);
```

To resume all in one code :

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeStrategies;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WebClientTest {

    @Mock
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Mock
    private WebClient mockedWebClient;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.exchangeStrategies(Mockito.any(ExchangeStrategies.class))).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
        Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.clientConnector(Mockito.any(ReactorClientHttpConnector.class))).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
        Mockito.when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mockedWebClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWebClient() {
        final MockedStatic<WebClient> webClientStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(WebClient.class);
        webClientStatic.when(WebClient::builder).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);

        final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder()
                        .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                                .defaultCodecs()
                                .maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024))
                        .build())
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.newConnection().compress(true)))
                .build();

        //It throws error if webClient is not mockedWebClient
        Assert.assertEquals(webClient, mockedWebClient);
    }
}
```

You can test it.

Comment: The MockedStatic type and `Mockito.mockStatic(..)` method are not importing with mockito-inline. It looks like they're now in Mockito core, but when I use core, I receive an error telling me to use mockito-inline:
```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
The used MockMaker PowerMockMaker does not support the creation of static mocks

Mockito's inline mock maker supports static mocks based on the Instrumentation API.
You can simply enable this mock mode, by placing the 'mockito-inline' artifact where you are currently using 'mockito-core'.
```

Comment: I used this way but I got NPE when the code jump in the client build part. Do you happen to know the possiable reason?

Comment: NVM, I figured the NPE because I didn't mock the `client.post().body(...)` correctly. After I fixed it, this method helped, and the unit test finally worked. And it can't work without mock the builder() first. Thanks a lot.