# Why this java WebClient mock is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

My server sends a request via WebClient and the code is below:

```
public String getResponse(String requestBody){
...
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request =
        client.post().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody));

    String resp =
        request.retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
            .doOnError(
                WebClientResponseException.class,
                err -> {
                  // do something
                })
            .block();

return resp;
}
```

I wrote a unit test for it and want to mock the WebClient so that I can receive the expected response:

```
when(webClientMock.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriMock);
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
when(responseMock.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just("response"));

String response = someServiceSpy.getResponse(requestBody);

assertEquals(Mono.just("response"), response);
```

However, the result is not the `"response"` but a html file. I think I made a mistake somewhere but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You don't include how `someService` gets initialized, but I suspect it has something to do with that.  You need to make sure your `webClientMock` is actually what `someService` is using as its `client`

Comment: @BenBorchard, not sure if I understand correctly. I spy the `someServiceSpy` at my code by `final SomeService someServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(someService);`

Comment: It appears that your `someService` object has a field inside of it called `client`.  You need to make sure (whether through mocking or spying, or just directly setting) that the `client` object is set to your `webClientMock` object that you create in your test.  It's not clear in the code you have posted whether you have done this or not.

Comment: @BenBorchard, thank you. In my code, the client is not a field of `someService`. The `client` was directly created by the `WebClient Builder`: ` WebClient client =
        WebClient.builder()
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(someValue))
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(provider)))
            .baseUrl(someURL)
            .defaultHeader(contentType, someValue)
            .build();`

Comment: I also tried to mock the WebClient Builder with the instruction on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857313/how-to-mock-spring-webclient-and-builder but it not working. I got a NullPointer exception on the client build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution that mocks the `WebClient` directly instead of putting the build logic into a new method to mock it. I wrote my solution here in case someone else needs it future:

Let me put the code example here:

```
    final WebClient client =
        WebClient.builder()
            .codecs(configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(someValue))
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(someProvider)))
            .baseUrl(someUrl)
            .defaultHeader(contentType, TEXT_XML_VALUE)
            .build();

    final WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> request =
        client.post().body(BodyInserters.fromValue(reqBody));
```

First, we must mock the static method `builder()` of `WebClient`. If this method is not mocked, mockito can't edit the behavior of this method, and the mocked `WebClient` would not be used. I found this from the answer to this StackOverflow question; you can read it for more details.: [How to mock Spring WebClient and builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69858080/8898054)

After mocked the `builder()` with the method provided by the above anwser, you will get a mocked `WebClient`, it's something like:

```
when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClientMock);
```

Then you can start to finish the rest of the work. In my sample code, the `client` will invoke `post()` and `body()`, so write the following:

```
    when(requestBodyUriMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
    when(requestHeadersMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseMock);
    when(responseMock.bodyToMono(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(expectedResponse));
```

My unit test returned the NPE at the beginning and it because I used

```
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
```

instead of

```
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(any())).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
```

I think it is because the code not "think" the `requestBodyUriMock` is using the `BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody` for some reasons that I haven't know yet. After I changed it to `any()`, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `client` referenced in your `getResponse` method is not set to the mock you have created (`webClientMock`) in your test.

If you are creating this `client` object in your `getResponse` method, I would suggest that you create it using a method that you could mock.  Something like

```
WebClient buildWebClient() {
  // build your webclient using the WebClientBuilder
}
```

You may want to throw a comment and or a `@VisibleForTesting` annotation on there so it is clear this method exists in order to make testing easier.

Then you can stub this method in your `someServiceSpy`:

```
Mockito.doReturn(mockWebClient).when(someServiceSpy).buildWebClient();
```

This will ensure that your `mockWebClient` is used in your `getResponse` method in your test.

---

Additionally, it seems as though your existing code needs a slight edit.

```
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
```

Should be

```
when(requestBodyUriMock.body(eq(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody)))).thenReturn(requestHeadersMock);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it could work. But finally I got NPE on `request.retrieve()`, not sure what is wrong...

Comment: I think you might need an `eq()` method when you mock they `body` method.  Adding to the answer