# MockWebServer not mocking WebClient in WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following code using Spring Webflux. I followed this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55346358/9973101), but still the mocking is not happening and the source code webclient response is being returned, could someone please help to understand why?

Service code:

```
@Service
class A {

    WebClient webClient;
    // other fields

    pubic A(Webclient webclient,
            /* other fields */) {
        this. webclient = webclient;
        // other fields
    }

    public Mono<ClassA> functionA() {
        return webclient
            .post()
            .uri(getUrl())
            .contentType("APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(getFormData()))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ClassA.class);
    }
}
```

Service test code:

```
class ATest {
    
    MockWebServer mockWebServer;
    A a;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach() {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start();
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(mockWebServer.url("/").toString());
        a = new A(webclient, /* other fields */)
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                .setStatus("HTTP/1.1 200"));
        
        Mono<ClassA> result = a.functionA();

        StepVerifier
                .create(result)
                .expectSubscription()
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the source for WebClient, but this, `WebClient.create(`, hints that you're creating an instance of WebClient.  If you want this to be a mock, then you need to assign that to `Mockito.mock(WebClient.class)`

Such as this

```
WebClient webClient = Mockito.mock(WebClient.class);
```

You also need to define behavior on your mock, or this will throw a NPE when it reaches the `.uri()` method call because the return value isn't defined on your mock.  So you'll have to configure your mock to return properly for all those chained methods.  If that's the Spring WebClient, I believe those return a Builder so you'll need one of these mocked out as well.

Personally, I would rewrite that test to look something like this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ATest {

    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

    @Mock
    private Mono<A> mono;

    @InjectMocks
    A a;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri("someURI")).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.body(any(BodyInserters.FormInserter.class))).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
        when(requestBodyUriSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.bodyToMono(A.class)).thenReturn(mono);

        Mono<A> result = a.functionA();
        A a = result.block();
    }
}
```

You'll want to replace the variables to match what your methods output, like to values from `getUrl()` and `getFormData()`